# Can i do someting before view being generated using spring mvc jsp shiro

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, shiro

I want to check session and add it's information to model, but i don't want to add code in every controller, so is there something I can use to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: If I understood you correctly (or close enough), then in spring mvc, there is a thing called ControllerAdviser. Look that up. That may have some use for you.

Comment: Thanks, I solve it by using interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use interceptor. Follow below url to get more idea about it.

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/

Comment: Thanks for your help, it perfectly solve my problem.

Comment: OK, sorry for being late